# Catalyst: how declare a global subroutine

Tags: perl, web-applications, dry, catalyst, subroutine

Hi i don't want to repeate the same code in the controllers, so i created a sub in the main MyApp package:

```perl
sub do_stuff {
    my $input = shift;

    do something
}
```

But then i want to use it in controller `MyApp::Controller::Foo`

```perl
sub test : Chained('base') Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    my $test = do_stuff($c->request->params->{s});

    do something more
}
```

i get following error:

> Caught exception in MyApp::Controller::Foo->test "Undefined subroutine
>   &MyApp::Controller::Foo::do_stuff called at
>   /home/student/workspace/MyApp/script/../lib/MyApp/Controller/Foo.pm
>   line 24,  line 1000."

**How can i create a subroutine / function to use global in all Catalyst Controllers???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle it is already available in all the modules that were used by your main `MyApp`.

But if it is defined in the main package, you must either call it from within that namespace (either `main` or your `MyApp` namespace), or import it into your current package namespace.

Depending on where it was defined, use one of those ways.

```
my $test = main::do_stuff($c->request->params->{s});
my $test = MyApp::do_stuff($c->request->params->{s});
```

The alternative is to import it into your namespace in each package.

```
package MyApp::Controller::Foo;
if (defined &MyApp::do_stuff) {
  *do_stuff = *MyApp::do_stuff;
}
```

With [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) you can check whether a subroutine exists.

---

On another note, maybe this `do_stuff` sub is better placed inside another module that has [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter). You can use it in all your controllers or other modules where you need it, and Exporter will take care of importing it into your namespace on its own.

Comment: @theguest Great. :) Also, welcome to SO. Please accept the answer by clicking the check-mark below the votes if it solved your problem. You can also up-vote good answers by clicking the top-pointing arrow. See the [faq#howtoask] if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

The context object (`$c`) that you pass to most methods in Catalyst is already an object of type `MyApp`, so if you say

```
$c->do_stuff($c->request->params->{s})
```

it is the same as calling

```
MyApp::do_stuff($c, $c->request->params->{s});
```

If you expect your global subroutines to make use of this context object, then you'll want to consider writing them as methods (i.e., subroutines in a package where the first argument is always an instance of the package):

```
# to be called like   $c->do_stuff("s")  to do something with form input "s"
sub do_stuff {
    my ($c, $param) = @_;

    ... do something with $c->request->param($param) ...
}
```